# Como passar os dados de um switch button para outra acivity?

Tags: java, android, layout

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicaçao mobile no AS que tem uma lista de cardviews. Nesses cards tenho um switch button que ao clicar em ON abrirá um alert dialog para confirmar a mudança de status. Porem estou com problemas ao passar as informaçoes, acredito eu, do switch button, tanto é que me retorna o erro abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O layout do meu cardview onde tem o switch button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/cv">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/board"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_qtd"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_nome"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_qtd"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_endereco"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_qtd"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_nome"
            />

        <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_bairro"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_qtd"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_nome"
            />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/simpleSwitch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Coletada"
            android:textOff="Não"
            android:textOn="Sim"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Esta é minha classe PalhetasColetadas reponsavel pelo cardview:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    View v = View.inflate(context,R.layout.card_view_palheta, null);
    TextView tv_nome = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_nome);
    tv_nome.setText(palhetas.get(i).getCodigo());
    TextView tv_endereco = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_endereco);
    tv_endereco.setText("Endereço: " + palhetas.get(i).getEndereco().getRua());
    TextView tv_bairro = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_bairro);
    tv_bairro.setText("Bairro: " + palhetas.get(i).getEndereco().getBairro());
    v.setTag(palhetas.get(i).getId());
    Switch simpleSwitch = (Switch) v.findViewById(R.id.simpleSwitch);
    simpleSwitch.setTextOn("Sim"); // displayed text of the Switch whenever it is in checked or on state
    simpleSwitch.setTextOff("Não");
    simpleSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
            ColetarActivity coletarActivity = new ColetarActivity();
            coletarActivity.cekstatus (isChecked);

        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

Na minha classe coleta é que eu verifico se o swicth button foi checado e dependendo dessa verificaçao eu faço um comando.

```
 private AlertDialog alertDialog() {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplication());
    builder.setMessage("Confirmar a coleta da palheta")
            .setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    confirmarPedidos();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
```

O problema está na mudança das classes, onde nao estou conseguindo passar as informaçoes do switch, alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A forma de iniciar a `ColetarActivity` está errada. Você não deve instanciar uma classe `Activity` manualmente. O correto seria algo como:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ColetarActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("check_status", message);
startActivity(intent);
```

Ou, por estar em um adapter, usando um `Context`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ColetarActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("check_status", message);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

E na outra `Activity`, para pegar o valor passado:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getBooleanExtra("check_status");
```

[Este artigo](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) dá uma explicação completa sobre o assunto.

Comment: Ao colocar seu codigo @Leonardo ele traz uns erros que postei na pergunta.

Comment: Só um complemento da resposta do Leonardo. Quando você utiliza `this` dentro de uma nova classe, você está dizendo para o sistema pegar aquela — nova — classe. Ou seja, o `new Intent(this, ColetarActivity.class)` está pegando a classe `OnCheckedChangeListener` e passando para o `intent`. Você pode usar o `context` (como foi supracitado na edição da resposta) ou `view.getContext();` no lugar do `this`.

Comment: Só um outro complemento, o correto atualmente é utilizar o ContextCompat. Em alguns casos pegando o Context da view, ou passando uma activity, pode gerar um Memory Leak do contexto, e isso na ContextCompat foi corrigido.

Comment: @Leonardo Lima agora estou com este outro erro, atualizado na pergunta.

Comment: @CarlosDiego erro meu, atualizei a resposta

Comment: @LeonardoLima eu ja tinha testado com a intent, e me retorna o erro: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: @CarlosDiego como o próprio erro indica, você deve incluir a flag indicada. Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: @LeonardoLima eu add essa tag, so que ao mudar o switch button de lado (on/off) ela muda pra uma activity em branca.

Comment: Há alguma informação no `logcat`?

Comment: @CarlosDiego bom, aí já é outro problema fora do escopo desta pergunta. Vc deve implementar adequadamente a `ColetarActivity` e seu `onCreate` para exibir algo nela.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr como estou passando via putExtra o id do cara logado, ele da um erro ao clicar no switch ele abre uma nova intent q nessa, nao há o id. So estranho, pq ele abre uma nova intent ao clica no switch. Mesmo so colocando um log, a tela em branco abre

Comment: Ele realmente manda o ON/OFF do switch pra classe, conforme conferido no LOG, porem tem esse outro pro da mudança de activity em branco

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma classe dentro da classe onde voce manipula sua listview:

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private List<Palheta> palhetas;

    public CustomAdapter(List<Palheta> palhetas) {
        this.palhetas = palhetas;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return palhetas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return palhetas.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card_view_palheta, null);
        TextView tv_nome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_nome);
        tv_nome.setText(palhetas.get(i).getCodigo());
        TextView tv_endereco = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_endereco);
        tv_endereco.setText("Endereço: " + palhetas.get(i).getEndereco().getRua());
        TextView tv_bairro = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_bairro);
        tv_bairro.setText("Bairro: " + palhetas.get(i).getEndereco().getBairro());
        view.setTag(palhetas.get(i).getId());
        Switch simpleSwitch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.simpleSwitch);
        simpleSwitch.setTextOn("Sim"); // displayed text of the Switch whenever it is in checked or on state
        simpleSwitch.setTextOff("Não");
        simpleSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "SIM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "NAO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Depois inicialize seu adapter passando a lista de palhetas:

```
private List<Palheta> palhetas;
private ListView lvPalheta;

Type usuariosListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Palheta>>(){}.getType();
CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(palhetas);
lvPalheta.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```